# javascript equivalent for python regex yes-pattern no-pattern

Tags: javascript, python

In python there is a syntax for - if a capture group exists then x else y
e.g.

```py
>>> pat = re.compile('(?:(a)|(c))b(?(1)a|c)') # should only match 'aba' or 'cbc'
>>> pat.match('abc')
None
>>> pat.match('aba')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='aba'>
>>> pat.match('cba')
None
>>> pat.match('cbc')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='cbc'>
```

How might one achieve a similar expression in javascript.

Leading to a general approach for converting the python regex syntax to javascript

```py
(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

I've tried a few ideas but haven't found an approach that's worked

Comment: What are the ideas you tried?

Comment: I was thinking about lookbehinds but that didn't work because of the order of the expressions.

Comment: After giving my answer, I think even this should work: `((?:a|c)b(?:a|c))` right? If you just want to match the same pattern again at the end, then you should go with the other existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64310709/2089675)...

Comment: The two suggestions work great - but I don't think I can turn them into a general approach. p.s. the use case is a javascript compiler for python. E.g. it's easy enough to take python's named capture groups and convert to javascript named capture group syntax. But for this syntax - I don't know if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, you don't need if/else syntax, you can backreference a single capture group:

```js
const pattern = /([ac])b\1/;
console.log(
  pattern.test('abc'),
  pattern.test('aba'),
  pattern.test('cbc'),
);
```

Comment: This may be better as a comment. The question specifically asks for a general approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Javascript has conditionals the way python does, but I think something like this should work:

```js
/(.+(?<=^(a|c))b(a|c))$/g
```

The `.+` at the front is used to actually accumulate tokens, and then the conditional is replaced with a positive look-behind (`?<=...`) but instead of a reference, we include the actual pattern we are looking for.